# Validation does not trigger on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate two fields (`reason` and `details`) on a form that is loaded as a modal.
(the validation works if the `inputs` are not loaded inside the modal). I am not sure what's the reason behind this.

I will be submitting via a webservice so I'm using the $("#save").click to trigger the validation and then send the data to the server.

My script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                reason: {
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 50,
                    required: true
                },
                details: {
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 999,
                    required: true
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.parent('.form-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });

        //save new item
        $("#save").click(function () {
          if ($('form').valid() == true) {
              //actions here
            }
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#addEntry").click(function () {
           $('#myModal').modal('show');

        });
    });

</script>
```

My html

```
<input id="addEntry" type="button" value="Add new medical entry" class="btn btn-default" />


    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade theindex" role="dialog">
        <form>
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->

            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header btn-success">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add new medical entry</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                        <h4>Reason</h4>
                       <div class="divDrop">
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <input class="form-control" id="txtReason" name="reason" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h4>Details</h4>
                        <div class="divDrop">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="txtDetails" name="details"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>

                <%--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>--%>
                <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                    <h4 class="modal-title leftPad1">Add prescription</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="divCateogyx">
                        <div class="divDrop">
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input class="form-control" id="txtMedicine" placeholder="search medicine by name, substance, or package" name="medicine" type="text" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 h5" id="divSelectedMeds">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <%--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>--%>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add media</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="divCateogyx">
                        <div class="divDrop">
                            <div id="accordion5" class="panel-group accordion_5">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a data-parent="#accordion5" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed" href="#item5_2"><span class="fa  accordion_icon"></span>Images, reports, or videos </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="item5_2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <dnn:DnnFilePicker ID="dnnFilePicker1" runat="server"></dnn:DnnFilePicker>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="save">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does the relevant `form` exist in the DOM when the `.validate()` method is called?

Comment: @Sparky I'm not sure how to check. Inside the page's html (if I view-source) the html is as is above

Comment: It should be working.  What exactly is happening during failure?  Are you getting any console errors when it fails?  You are targeting the `form` tag itself.  If you have any other `<form>` elements on the page, only the first instance will be used.  Try a more specific jQuery selector.

Comment: @Sparky nothing is happening. Would you like to have a look via team viewer?

Comment: I copied your HTML and JS locally, and after including the appropriate JS (Bootstrap, jQuery, jQuery validate), your validation works for me.  You have no validation error msgs, but clicking Save without adding anything in the fields highlights both with a red border.  I guess you've checked, but does your HTML really include all required JS?  Can you include here the *full* HTML and JS of the simplest version of your code?

Comment: Please don't post "full" HTML/JavaScript... just the minimum required that reproduces the problem.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Again... you are targeting the `form` tag itself. If you have any other `<form>` elements on the page, only the first instance will be used. Try a more specific jQuery selector or add an `id` to the form tag and use an `id` selector.

Comment: @Sparky I have added an ID to the form <form id="theForm" > and validating like:  $('#theForm').validate({... but still nothing. Any ideas? Again, if the form is not in the modal, the validation works fine.

Comment: @Sparky Whenever I target the form by ID even if it's not on the modal, it does not validate it.

Comment: I have no idea.  There is nothing you've shown that explains what you describe.  Side note:  `.valid()` returns a boolean, so there is no need to compare it to anything.  In other words `if ($('form').valid() == true)` can simply be `if ($('form').valid())`

Comment: @Sparky After debugging I found out that even though I add an id to the form, then the ID disappears from the form. That is why it doesn't work by targetting the form's ID. I'm using a CMS which I believe is manipulating some elements. However, again, when the form is not part of the modal it works...

Comment: If your CMS is manipulating things, then you need to focus on the ***rendered*** HTML markup as displayed in the browser.  JavaScript does not care about your CMS or server-side code.  Then look for other `<form>` elements, since I explained before, your selector will only match the first instance on the page.

Comment: @Sparky yes, so the <form> target works. But still can't figure out why it doesn't work on the modal. If you would like to have a look then you can connect via team viewer. Would you like to?

Comment: Show us the ***rendered*** HTML markup as displayed in the browser.

Comment: @Sparky ok its here http://pastebin.com/x2TEyW2L

Comment: I don't understand what you're showing us in the pastebin.   There's only one `form` and it's not within a modal.  Your modal contains no `form` tags at all.  You cannot call `.validate()` on a `form` that does not exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `.validate()` method to just after you show the modal.  This way, the form exists when you initialize validation.

```
$("#addEntry").click(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');  // show the form
    $('#myForm').validate({          // initialize validation on the form
        rules: { ....
        ....
    });
});
```

Also, since your pastbin is showing another `form` outside of the modal, you must use a more specific selector to target the `form` within the modal.

Comment: I have tried this, but still doesn't work. I have moved the form tags around the <h4>Reason</h4> also and that doesn't work either. I believe when you say 'use a more specific selector to target the form within the modal.' is where the answer is, but still can't figure it out.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET, I've given it all I can.  It's up to you to sort it all out now.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET, there are lots of ways to use selectors without putting an `id` on the `form`.  Have you tried something like this... `$('#myModal form')` which will only target the `form` element within `#myModal`.  However, if the  relevant `form` tag does not exist until after you show the modal, nothing else will work... you can **only** call `.validate()` *after* the form is constructed in the DOM.